# Images and contents don't show when a Data Source item is cloned

Tags: experience-editor, item-clones

I am adding a rendering in Experience Editor and when it asks for a `datasource`, I am cloning a `datasource` item within that pop up and the rendering is using the `cloned datasource` item. But when I browse the page that item content is not showing.
When I modify the content in the `cloned datasource` item then it starts showing on the page.

Can someone please tell what story is behind it? Why the content is not showing if I am using then cloned `datasource` unless I modify the content after cloning!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: in short, If we use cloned item as datasource, shall it render all the fields ?

Comment: It works in my machine but not in SIT and UAT. dont know what to check.

Answer (score 0):

A clone in Sitecore is an item that is not just a copy of your original item, but one that inherits all the field values from the original item. Note, that if you update a field in the original item, the corresponding field in the cloned item will also be updated.

Likely your original item has multiple content versions and you select not the latest one while cloning it. If so then before cloning your item, ensure to select the desired version of your original item. Read more about the impact of versions on clones [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/the-impact-of-versions-on-clones.html).

Comment: Thanks @Kate for the information. And in my case there is only one numbered version for  a language version of the item. And interesting thing is the same cloned item, in my local environment, is working fine but on SIT it does not render the field contents.